# Ruby - How to add a character at the beginning and end of a string

Tags: ruby

How do I add a apostrophe at the beginning and end of a string?

```
string = "1,2,3,4"
```

I would like that string to be:

```
'1','2','3','4'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result = []
"1,2,3,4".split(',').each do |c|
  result << "'#{c.match /\d+/}'"
end
puts result.join(',')

'1','2','3','4'
```

Answer (score 11):

Not sure, if this is what you want:

```
>> s = "1,2,3,4"
>> s.split(',').map { |x| "'#{x}'" }.join(',')
=> "'1','2','3','4'"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use regular expression to find digits

```
string = "1,2,3,4"
string.gsub(/(\d)/, '\'\1\'')
#=> "'1','2','3','4'"
```

Comment: or to go above 9: string.gsub(/(\d+)/, '\'\1\'')

Answer (score 2):

str.insert(0, 'x')
str.insert(str.length, 'x')

After seeing your edit.

```
q = "1,2,3,4"

ar = q.split(',')

ar.each{|i| i.insert(0, "'").insert(-1, "'")}

q = ar.join(',')
```