# Rails - Formatting Comma Separated Values for SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I take this following comma separated string:

111, 222, 333

and have it properly formatted to the following sql:

select all from table where id IN ('111', '222', '333')

I'm using prepared statement with find_by_sql. Please help.

Comment: duplicate of your own question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249482/ruby-how-to-add-a-character-at-the-beginning-and-end-of-a-string/5249814#5249814

Comment: that link is not a page with my question.

Comment: but whos? author is the same user as you

Answer (score 2):

You can format the ids using map:

```
'111,222,333'.split(',').map { |id| "'#{id}'" }.join(',')
```

There is a method to wrap a string with characters, but it escapes me. Hence, the ugly map block.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "111, 222, 333"
ids = string.gsub(/(\d)/, '\'\1\'')
query = "select all from table where id IN (#{ids})"
```